# Can ghex show raw hex bytes on /dev/sdb?

Tags: text-editor, binary

I wanted to look into raw bytes in my /dev/sdb, so I called the `ghex` like this:

```
sudo ghex /dev/sdb&
```

and got an *empty* window plus errors in the command line window:

```
(ghex:4871): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_main_quit: assertion `main_loops != NULL' failed

(ghex:4871): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_main_quit: assertion `main_loops != NULL' failed
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possibly the *immediate* error comes from trying to run a GUI desktop application with `sudo` (instead of `gksudo` or at least `sudo -H`); however, I don't think using a hex editor to try to read a whole block device is something I'd try - why not look at using `dd` to extract some particular blocks of interest?

Comment: I tried to open a root-owned file with `sudo ghex <file>` and it worked fine. As for the `dd` - I need something more interactive/graphical.

Comment: Also I've just tried to use `gksudo` instead of `sudo` - `Gtk-CRITICAL` errors went away, but the `ghex` window was still empty

Answer (score 3):

I sincerely hope for you that that was a USB stick because what you just did is ***extremely dangerous!***

As this is a block device, you cannot "just" `ghex` this on a multi-user multi-tasking OS.  It's just not possible, even when the disk is unmounted and not any more after the disk has been ejected...

Anyway, If you **really, really** want to have a *more or less safe look* at the MBR, execute the following command:

**Warning:**

### dd is the abbreviation of Disk Destroyer!

```
dd if=/dev/sdX of=~/home/Documents/MBR.HEX bs=512 count=1
ghex ~/home/Documents/MBR.HEX
```

Where `X` stands for the disk containing your boot record.

If you want the unsafe version, **don't come crying afterwards**, download a single-user single-tasking OS like [FreeDOS](http://www.freedos.org/), boot that and use a tool like [Hex51a](https://www.hackcanada.com/blackcrawl/hack.html) and run that and you can do anything you want, ***including totally unsafe things!***

#### >:-)

Comment: Please don't assume I'm rookie... The "multi-user multi-tasking OS" allows me to call `dd`. Why not to do that interactively/graphically in read-only mode? Anyway, I'm thankful for your quasianswer

Comment: Why would I want to dive into another OS when I only want to see raw bytes on the block device which I've written myself in Ubuntu?